# UDF Function - IfFormat

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a function that check if a cell's format matches the designated input. Ideally, I'd like the user to be able to specify "bold", "euro", etc. The error I'm getting right now is 'user-defined type not defined'. Could anyone help me with this? Thank you so much.

```
Function IfFormat(C As Range, F As Text) As Boolean
    If F = C.NumberFormat Then
        IfFormat = True
        Else: IfFormat = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I don't think `Text` is a type. Try `String` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently I haven't had my morning coffee yet. Also, how can I allow the user to type "Euro" instead of the literal custom format?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
if F = "Euro" and C.NumberFormat = (whatever that custom format is) then
  IfFormat = True

Etc.
```

Comment: I looked it up. So the number format you use would be `"[$€-2] #,##0.00"`.

Comment: Ok - that's kinda what I was thinking. Just wasn't sure whether there was an easier way to do it.